# Query without plain SQL in Android Room Database

Tags: android, android-room

In Android **Room** database, e.g. to find all users from table, we can:

```
@Query(“SELECT * FROM Users”)
fun getUsers(): List<User>
```

But can we get smthing without plain SQL code `SELECT * FROM Users` ?

In **Spring Framework** we can, e.g.:

```
fun findAllUsers(): List<User>
```

And then we got all necessary users, without SQL code in annotation, but with annotation also can.

The question is: can we get something WITHOUT `@Query` annotation?

Comment: The answer is NO.

Comment: Even in Spring, you need to implement that function. Or something is writing query for you

Comment: @cricket_007 in Spring I don't need to implement this function. Also I can use abstract function like: `findByTitleOrderByTitleAsc(title: String)` without any annotation and implementation.

Comment: Sure, but based on the method text, it magically writes queries for you. Room is not such a library

Comment: @cricket_007 it clearly that query code in Spring is generated, and my question was if room can do the same.

Comment: It's not stated in the Room documentation, so not out of the box, no. Back to Spring: Not all databases use SQL syntax, so there's some extra library you're using that generates queries

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, not all databases use SQL syntax, but mentioned above functions namings also working, e.g. for mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But can we get smthing without plain SQL code SELECT * FROM Users ?

No.

> can we get something WITHOUT @Query annotation?

Also no.